# Next.js , pass getServerSideProps and children props in the page component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my Next project

I have the following structure inside the pages folder

```
components (folder)
  Layout.js
  Navbar.js
  Footer.js
_app.js
shoes.js
index.js
```

I have in my `_app.js`

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  ) 
}
```

Layout contains some common parts of the app like `Navbar.js` and  `Footer.js` Inside Layout I have

```
export async function getServerSideProps(){   
    const req = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=3`) 
    const posts = await req.json();
    return {
        props:{posts}
    } 
}  

    export default function Layout({ ... props }){  

    return(
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>   
           <Head> </Head>
           <Navbar />  
           <div> {props.posts} </div>
           {props.children}  
           <Footer/>   
        </ThemeProvider> 
    )
}
```

Layout contains the top and bottom part of the app and then its children go between - in this case the index and shoes pages.

I want to get some data in Layout using `getServerSideProps` that I will be free to pass around

As is now, inside Layout, I can see only children as props. I dont see posts. I tried different approaches below to insert posts in the Layout component props, nothing worked.

```
export default function Layout({ children, posts }){ 
export default function Layout({...{ children, posts }}){
```

How can I resolve this? Please help. Thanks

Comment: You have two options: **1)** fetch the data server-side in `_app` inside `getInitialProps` then pass it down to the `Layout` component; **2)** fetch the data on the client (`useEffect`) in the `Layout` component itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use `getServerSideProps` in page components that you have in the pages folder. NextJS will see if there is a `getServerSideProps` function and if yes, it will invoke it and populate the data. But this only happens if NextJS is in control of the page component. So, even if you store it in the `pages` directory, but you import the component in some other file, you are basically taking the control away from NextJS and instantiating the component yourself.

[Reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)

Comment: thanks for the answer, you are right. The problem is that even if i move the Layout inside the pages folder, I cannot pass it children and props from `getServerSideProps` . I still only see children, not other props. Do you have any solution? Thanks

Comment: If you are using that data in the Layout component, I am assuming you need that for all the routes. You need to re-evaluate if that is the case and can it be avoided. Also, you should consider moving the data fetching to client side if it is not needed for SEO.

Comment: @codebot Simply moving `Layout` to the pages folder won't work if you're still using that component inside other pages, and not as a page itself.

Comment: @juliomalves Ok. so , I cannot have Layout outside pages folder, I cannot do any `getServerSideProps` inside the `_app.js` and now I cannot reuse it inside other pages...SO what is the solution here? I just want to reuse Layout that happens to contain other repeatable components such as Footer and it also does a `getServerSideProps` to get some data. What is the solution here? Thanks

Comment: @VighneshRaut by "data fetching to client side" do you mean using `useEffect` inside the Layout? I am conserned if this is going to break the app since it will end up having `useEffect` , `getServerSideProps` and `getStaticProps` in its pages. If having all of these in the same app is comon, I can go ahead and use them. Thanks again

Comment: There are multiple ways you can achieve this. If you always want this to be on the server, then, you will have to do it in all the pages via `getServerSideProps`. If you are ok with this being rendered on the client, you can either create a hook that does the data fetching, or you can use the React Context API and fetch data in provider and use it to wrap all your pages, or the simple `useEffect` approach would also work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Layout component as a wrapper only in your pages, then you can pass the props to it.

See how we achieved it [here](https://github.com/CodeForAfrica/TwoopsTrackerUI/blob/main/src/pages/about.js). It might require some changes to your component structure, If you edit your question with your component structure I can help you with it.

so you have to take your `Layout` component and repeat it in every component under the pages folder.

so in `_app`, you will have

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
      <Component {...pageProps} />
  ) 
}
```

you will move your static props from where it it now to all the components under `pages`
Your Layout component will become

```
    export default function Layout({ ... props }){  

    return(
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>   
           <Head> </Head>
           <Navbar />  
           <div> {props.posts} </div>
           {props.children}  
           <Footer/>   
        </ThemeProvider> 
    )
}
```

Now assuming you have a page `index.js` under pages folder, it will become like this. You will have to do this for all the pages.

```
function Index({posts,..props}) {
  return (
    <Layout posts={posts}>
    // your current home content will be here
    </Layout>
  ) 
}

export async function getServerSideProps(){   
    const req = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=3`) 
    const posts = await req.json();
    return {
        props:{posts}
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried something like ` About({ partners, ...props })` and didnt work, I still see only the children as props and nothing else. I also dont want to desable automatic static optimization, so I cannot edit the `_app.js` . I edited my original question to add more data, can you please take a look? Thanks

Comment: i have updated my answer to what i think you should do. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks. I believe that this is the only way to do it, considering all the limitations. So the Layout is in every page and gets props by that page. That is nice, but you have to do more requests in `getServerSideProps` per  page. One for the page itself and one for the Layout. As an alternative, how about I do a simple `useEffect` inside the Layout to get some data? Will it affect the rest of the app since `getServerSideProps` is pre-rendered and `useEffect` isnt ? Thanks

Comment: well, yes, the `getServerSideProps` runs on every request regardles of where you put it, so it is not a performance issue, but just repetition of code, and I will extract the code into a library and call it from the `getServerSideProps` instead. 
And if you use useEffect, you might have some flash of content, since it will load the page and later try to load the post from the frontend.