# how to render async page components as a child in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I am using the `next.js` new functionality to render content using `SSR`, I am making component `async` as `docs` says.

So this is my simple page component

```js
export default async function Home() {

    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/get-quotes");
    const quotes = await res.json();

    return (
        <main className={styles.main}>
            <h1>Hello Visrut</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Total quotes: {quotes.length}</span>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}
```

I have `authenticated` and `non-authenticated` routes in my application, what I am doing to separate them in `_app.tsx`

```js
// _app.tsx
interface AppProps {
  Component: React.ElementType;
  pageProps: Record<string, unknown>;
}

const App: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  if (router.pathname.includes("home")) {
    return <Home />;   // Error: 'Home' can't be used as a JSX component, Its return type Promise<Home> is not a valid JSX component.
  }

  return (
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <Navbar />
      <Head />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <Footer />
    </AuthContextProvider>
  )
};

export default App;
```

I want to render the `Home` component which does not require authentication, it seems like I can't just directly put it as children also because of the `async` keyword.

I am also getting this error on the browser while directly rendering `async` component into other normal components in `next.js`

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Objects are not valid as a React child (found: \[object Promise\])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658765/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-found-object-promise)

Comment: @Jeffin thanks but I saw that earlier, they are suggesting removing the `async` keyword but that's not what I want when doing in `next.js` I also left comment there below already.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Move your async code into `getServerSideProps` function and pass the response into your `Home` component as Props

## Next 12

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/get-quotes");
  const quotes = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      quotes: quotes,
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}
```

```
export default function Home({quotes}) {
    return (
        <main className={styles.main}>
            <h1>Hello Visrut</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Total quotes: {quotes.length}</span>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}
```

## Next 13

```
import { use } from "react";

async function getQuotes() {
  return await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/get-quotes", {
    cache: "no-store",
  }).json();
}

export default function Home() {
  const quotes = use(getQuotes());
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <h1>Hello Visrut</h1>
      <div>
        <span>Total quotes: {quotes.length}</span>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am using `next 13` and they removed this feature from the `app` directory, maybe even if I try to create component as you told me I won't able to import it in other component see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70939164/next-js-pass-getserversideprops-and-children-props-in-the-page-component

Comment: but thanks for your answer I will try to incorporate this somehow, let's see. I will update this thread afterward.

Comment: I've updated with Next13 code @Visrut, please mark it as answer if it helps

Comment: I was using it from a component other than `page.jsx`. So `getServerSideProps` didn't work. but `use` worked for me! :D